# Apex Action Status tag with standard controller

Tags: visualforce, apex

When i click on the contact,the details of the contacts are not displayed,please let me know the changes to be done.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">

   You are displaying contacts from{!account.name} name.
   click a Contact's name to view his or her details.
 </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="contacts"> 
          <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.contacts}" var="ac"> 
          <apex:column >
           <apex:commandLink reRender="details">
              {!ac.name}
            <apex:param name="cid" value="{!ac.id}" />
          </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:dataTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>

                <apex:outputPanel id="details">
                 <apex:actionStatus startText="Requesting...">
                  <apex:facet name="stop">
                   <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.acid}" relatedList="false" title="false"/>
                   </apex:facet>
                 </apex:actionStatus>  
               </apex:outputPanel>



</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

This is the screenshot of my VFpage:

> `chrome-extension://mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg/fsCaptured.html`

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is as follow:

```
<apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.Parameters.cid}" relatedList="false" title="false"/>
```

The apex param has to be called by its name.

screenshot of the VFpage

> chrome-extension://mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg/fsCaptured.html